# How to enforce child-of-X limitation on template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

*Suppose I want to enforce the limitation that the template parameter passed in is a child of Foo.*

Is there a way to enforce this through type-traits?  A compile-time `static_assert` failure would be great.

In the code below, let's make it a two-part (separate) question.

1. Allow only `My_Limited_Template<Bar>` to compile.
2. Allow only `My_Limited_Template<TBar>` to compile.

**EDIT**
I apologize for the bad naming: `TBar` and `TBaz` are meant to be non-template classes on purposes.  I just attached T in front of the names to disambiguate from the classes in Part 1.

**CODE**

```
struct Foo { };                // no
struct Bar : public Foo { };   // yes
struct Baz { };                // no

template< typename T >
struct TFoo { };                       // no
struct TBar : public TFoo<TBar> { };   // yes
struct TBaz { };                       // no

template< typename T >
struct My_Limited_Template
{
  // Part One:
  //   My_Limited_Template<Foo>  // disallow
  //   My_Limited_Template<Bar>  // allow
  //   My_Limited_Template<Baz>  // disallow
  // 
  // Part Two:
  //   My_Limited_Template<TFoo<int>> // disallow
  //   My_Limited_Template<TBar>      // allow
  //   My_Limited_Template<TBaz>      // disallow
};
```

Comment: So the second part would be *"only allow parameters which are derived from TFoo using CRTP"*?

Comment: @jrok +1 if you could involve CRTP, that would be even better, but I'm not sure if that's possible!

Comment: What I meant is that **you** used CRTP when deriving TBar. Is that the only kind of `TFoo` child you want to allow or is it ok to have something like `struct X : TFoo<int> { };`?

Comment: @jrok - yes, I understood what you meant.  What I meant was, my original intention was to enforce a CRTP requirement, but since I didn't think that was possible at all, I didn't mention anything (implying a looser requirement: as in `struct X : TFoo<int> { }` is fine).

Comment: Leonid's answer does the trick with your original requirements (with CRTP). See [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/NzE0MT$1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you made an error in definition of `TBar` and `TBas`, check that my modification is correct.

```
#include <type_traits>    

struct Foo { };                // don't allow this
struct Bar : public Foo { };   // allow this
struct Baz { };                // don't allow this

template< typename T > struct TFoo { };                       
template< typename T > struct TBar : public TFoo<TBar<T>> { }; 
template< typename T > struct TBaz { };                       

template< typename T >
struct My_Limited_Template
{
        static_assert(
                (std::is_base_of<Foo,T>::value && !std::is_same<T,Foo>::value)
                || 
                (std::is_base_of<TFoo<T>,T>::value && !std::is_same<T,TFoo<T>>::value),
                "fail2"
        ); 
};
```

Comment: I don't think that your second part is right (why are you assuming that the question is wrong?). IIUC, the question requires that `T` be a subclass of some (unspecified) instantiation of `TFoo`, whereas your answer requires that `T` be a subclass of specifically `TFoo<T>`.